# redirect sub page to external site sub page

Tags: mod-rewrite

Will this code redirect a sub page at domain 1 to a sub page at domain 2

**Code:**

```
#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/docs/(.+)"  "http://domain2.com/docs/$1"  [R,L]
```

Comment: I dont understand how to specify page 1 in domain 1

Comment: Did you try running the code?